# How to read the lengthof an array of objects in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm making an dashboard to show a resume of the items that my system is bringing from the database. I'm using MEAN.

I want to know, how to read the length of an array of objects to pass the number as parameter to the chart.

I have the objects like this in my angular layer:

[image]

My angular controller is like this:

```
$scope.projects = Projects.query();
$scope.users = Users.query();
$scope.tasks = Tasks.query();
$scope.numberOfTasks = $scope.users.length;
```

And the `.length` not works for me! Always returns `2`. I tried to see the keys of my object using `console.log(Object.keys($scope.tasks));`, and returned `["$promise", "$resolved"]`

Someone can help?

Comment: It should just be myobject.length

Comment: you can use `$scope.projects.length`

Comment: It not works for me! Always returns `2`. I tried to see the keys of my object using `console.log(Object.keys($scope.tasks));`, and returned `["$promise", "$resolved"]`

Comment: because as per the image your project has two objects ..

Comment: This seems that your `query()` method is an AJAX call .. ???

Comment: Yes, but with users, and tasks, returns two always

Comment: @Chandan, it connects with the API Rest in the back-end

Comment: see my answer below.. you will need to handle the promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `query()` is an AJAX call, you will need to handle this call and in the success promise or callback you can get the length as follows -

```
    Projects.query().then(function(res){

        var projectLength = res.length;
        $scope.numberOfTasks = projectLength;

    }, function(err){// handle error here });
```

You can do the same for other `query()` functions as well.

Comment: Returned this error `TypeError: Projects.query(...).then is not a function` (sorry if i'm beeing noob, i'm just learning)

Comment: I'm using `query()` from the `ngResource` module

Comment: can you try above one... and let me know

Comment: With the code:
`$scope.projects = Projects.query().$promise.then(function(res){
        var projectLength = res.length;
        $scope.projectsLength = projectLength;
    }, function(err){});

 console.log($scope.projectsLength);`

returned `undefined` in the console

Comment: you need to put the logs inside the function `function(res){ var projectLength = res.length; $scope.projectsLength = projectLength; console.log(projectLength) }` like this.

Comment: And how can i access the `$scope.projectsLength` out of the function?

Comment: Since the length you get is inside an function call, it is not directly accessible from outside. You can assign this to $scope variable and display it from there. However if you want this length to be sent to another API backend call, then you will need to call that API from inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `$scope.projects.length` to get size of the Array `$scope.projects` as you do with `$scope.numberOfTasks = $scope.users.length;`

Array.length is property available in JS for any array - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

Comment: It not works for me! Always returns `2`. I tried to see the keys of my object using `console.log(Object.keys($scope.tasks));`, and returned `["$promise", "$resolved"]`

Comment: Aha, now we talking :) the problem is not in Array length, its the way promises work. Please check @Chandan answer, it's about it